# Drop down menu with fixed navbar

Tags: css, navbar, fixed, dropdown

I have fixed navigation in my site, but when i scroll down page mouse hover, drop down open but with a gap and as soon as i put mouse hover on it, that drop down go top around 10px. Can any one solve my issue please? my link is

http://blackrovermedia.com/demo/

Comment: we need to see the code, it seems the problem is here `.nav li ul, .et-fixed-header .nav li ul` add this part of `css` to your question.

Comment: yes you are right you got the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of the modifications I did : http://prntscr.com/er46v9

Basically, when you hover the link the sub-UL has a top of 52px but you forgot to remove (to those 52px) the paddingTop of 11px of the A itself therefore there's a gap ;) !

Comment: Thanks @vivick you told me a perfect solution